# Error message from creating a virtual device on Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android studio and tried to setup a virtual device. Everything was installed but when I was about to launch it I got this message

"The emulator process for avd pixel_3a_api_29 has terminated"

The emulator will come up for few seconds then disappear. I have not been able to get pass this error message. I googled with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling VT-X from bios .if still not work then try genemotion

Comment: Please where can I  do that?

Comment: In BIOS there is option called VT-X

Answer (score -1):

enabling VT-X from bios from setting in advance option

Steps:-

Turn ON the System
Repeatedly press Esc key at startup.
Press the F10 key for BIOS Setup.
Press the right arrow key to System Configuration tab, Select Virtualization Technology and then press the Enter key.
Select Enabled and press the Enter key.
Press the F10 key and select Yes and press the Enter key to save changes and Reboot.

Comment: I am looking for steps to do that and cant find it

Comment: Again when I did syteminfo.exe under Hyper-v requirements, I have virtualization enable in Firmware: Yes

Comment: follow above steps

Comment: Go to Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features -> click Turn Windows features on or off -> un-check Hyper-V -> click OK

Comment: Hyper-v is not checked at all. I just checked it